# How can I get the value of this array in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord

How can I get the value of this array

```
const { model, Schema} = require("mongoose")

let ticketSchema = new Schema({
    GuildID : String,
    MembersID: [String],
    TicketID: String,
    ChannelID: String,
    Closed: Boolean,
    Locked: Boolean,
    Type: String,
    Claimed: Boolean,
    ClaimedBy: String,
    Open:Boolean,
    OpenBy:String,
})

module.exports = model("Ticket", ticketSchema);
```

**Example:**

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63d8340e0a415466f7ad55f0"),
  GuildID: '1066373193767592047',
  MembersID:
  [0]:811664013313310720
  TicketID: '2',
  ChannelID: '1069728239200780398',
  Closed: false,
  Locked: false,
  Type: 'Hola',
  Claimed: false,
  Open: false,
  OpenBy: '811664013313310720',
  __v: 0
}
```

How can I get the value of **MembersID:[0]:811664013313310720** in this case it would be **811664013313310720**  I need it to check on a system

Try methods with findOne, Find

Comment: Do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cXzusUa3SDW)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use MongoDB Driver and the following syntax can extract the property MembersID

```
data = await dbo.collection(COLLECTION).find({},{projection:MembersID:1}).toArray()
```

MongoDB Drivers → Node.js

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const config = require('../config/mongodb'); // Your Own Connections Details
let db, dbo;
  const COLLECTION = 'Ticket';
  db = await MongoClient.connect(config.url, config.connection);
  dbo = await db.db(config.database);
  let data = [];
  const options = {
    projection: { MembersID: 1 }
  };
data = await dbo.collection(COLLECTION).find({}, options).toArray();
data[0].MembersID // Access the Array
```

Mongoose

```
data = await dbo.collection('Ticket').find({}).exec();
```

Point to Note

- The MembersID is a type of Integer, ensure you have right type when comparing
- The MongoDB client connection details is omitted. [MongoDB Connect to DB Official Document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#std-label-node-connect-to-mongodb)
- Mongoose Refer to this document [Mongoose find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find)